# Android Pop-up Menu with material design in ListView

Tags: android, listview, animation, popupmenu

How can i create the pop up menu exactly in my Android list view like this having material design effects and pop up animation? can anybody help with the code?

When i click on the 3 dots the Menu should popup on its top like in the below image: 
[image: POPUP Menu]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html

Comment: not clear what you want!

Comment: I am having a image button in my xml layout and i want to display the pop up menu on clicking the image button. i tried the simple PopupMenu that android provides but it is displaying popup downwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use the PopUp Menu.

Here is a link tk more information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html

You can also provide a custom layout to it, if it's another layout you want.

Comment: I want to change the gravity of PopupMenu I tried this:                 PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu (parent.getContext(), view, Gravity.TOP); But it is still displaying below the button

Comment: What about the Alert Dialog? It is always on top and in the middle. It has an overlay though http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

Comment: No not alert dialog but what i want is pop up menu exactly like in the above picture

Comment: You cannot control the placement of the Popup Menu. What about the PopupWindow? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html